# UFW Block in Syslog - Why are many different IPs trying to connect to my server

Tags: networking, security, firewall, ufw, traffic

first of all I want to clear up that I'm not a network expert and just trying to understand things. I hope I can find help here and get a bit smarter.. I'm hosting a service on a Ubuntu 22.04 vps. That service is behind a reverse proxymanager and can be reached through the internet.

After checking /var/log/syslog I could see that many different IP adresses are trying to connect to my server using TCP or UDP on random Ports.

e.g:

```
Feb 27 15:38:24 srv-ub kernel: [241679.951328] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=x.163.125.213 DST=xx.xx.xx.231 LEN=44 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=242 ID=14405 PROTO=TCP SPT=42436 DPT=21297 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Feb 27 15:39:09 srv-ub kernel: [241686.038366] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=x.49.149.1 DST=xx.xx.xx.231 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=19849 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4086 DPT=123 LEN=16
Feb 27 15:39:27 srv-ub kernel: [241703.765119] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=x.136.225.9 DST=xx.xx.xx.231 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=109 ID=0 PROTO=TCP SPT=62985 DPT=9300 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

**There are many more attempts from different Ips and different countries like China Bulgaria Cyprus etc. (I checked using whois)**

My UFW rules are following:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
21/tcp                     DENY IN     Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

My question is: is this normal traffic or is somebody trying to get access to my server? is there anything I should do against it?

Thank y'all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

> is this normal traffic

yes.

> or is somebody trying to get access to my server?

yes. Every machine with a public IPv4 address is scanned by malicious botnets hundreds of times per day.

> is there anything I should do against it?

As with any machine, disable password login for SSH, don't run services that don't have to positively exposed to the internet. Especially the fact that you have port 8080 open at all, and 22, 443, 8080 not restricted to TCP says that you're locking down as strictly as possible without running into problems.

Port 21 is FTP, and unencrypted. This is 2023, not 1993; there's absolutely no good reason to run an FTP server exposed to the internet. FTP is an obsolete protocol, insecure, and comes, through its tendency to open separate data and control connections on different ports, to problems setting it up securely behind a firewall, anyways. It isn't standardized to deal with any character encodings, and even the directory listing format is ambiguous. So, don't use it to offer listable directories, and don't use it to offer third parties some place to upload to, as with unencrypted authentication, it's inherently unsafe to connect to it.

There's multiple competing protocols with wide support. In the web world, webDAV was/is somewhat popular, in the cloud world, there's multiple FOSS implementations of the AWS S3 protocol/REST API; if you just need a software repository for other people to download files, there's easier solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I’m aware of not using FTP.. one day I specifically denied it in ufw but I don’t know the reason anymore. One more question if you don’t mind. Is it secure enough if the basic rule goes by Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed) or are there specific ports I should block like the ftp port in my ufw config.